# Access 2013 having clause non-unique salary

Tags: ms-access, having

I'm using the *having* clause and I have to **display a list of non-unique salaries i.e. where two or more workers have the same salary. In each case show how many workers receive that salary.**

This is what i have so far.

```
SELECT 
FROM workers 
GROUP BY salary 
HAVING COUNT ;
```

I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: I presume the "access" in the title is MS Access and changed the tag accordingly.

Comment: As a start, in regular SQL it'd be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) ppl_with_salary, salary FROM workers GROUP BY salary HAVING COUNT(*)>1`, however I'm too lazy to look up the exact syntax for Access :)

Comment: yes thanks, can you help? i have just figured out how to display the non-unique salary, but how do i show the amount of workers as well?

Comment: its ok, i got it! SELECT COUNT(*) As No_Workers, salary
FROM workers
GROUP BY salary
HAVING ( COUNT(salary) > 1 );

Comment: @prince You may want to add that as an answer and accept it, nothing wrong with accepting your own answer if you figure it out without anyone else answering :)